# How can I persuade Redditors on a Subreddit to use Stack Exchange for the same subject?

Tags: reddit

Some SEs would gain more value from more experts, and subreddits usually have more users than a given SE.

For example — How can you convince users at r/ask_lawyers, r/auslaw, r/canadalaw, r/law, r/lawschool, r/uklaw, etc. to to use [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to *try* to get folks to move (or augment) their participation in one community to another, try posting content from the other community in a way that encourages them to come over.

Share blog posts, good content, etc.

In short, you cannot *make* anyone move from one to another - but if you provide enough "good" content from the other to the one, you might garner some new users